# Image picker flutter issue

Tags: flutter, project

when I try to use image_picker and run the flutter project it gives me error

A problem occurred configuring project ':image_picker_android'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\ZerpSteve\Documents\flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker_android-0.8.5\android\build.gradle' from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in your flutter project folder and rerun your project.

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

Comment: I've done this a few times but still give me the same error